# How to add a new node in a existing MinIo cluster

Tags: minio, data-storage, file-storage

I have a multi node multi drive minio cluster runing on 1.1.1.1 and 1.1.1.2 Ip. Both have 3 drives each and mounted to /disk1,/disk2 and /disk3.This is an up and runing system.Now I want to add a new minio node with IP 1.1.1.3 with same 3 drives to previous cluster.I am using a load balancer runing at 1.1.1.10.

I have followed official document and installed minio on 1.1.1.3 system and my /etc/default/minio file of 1.1.1.3 looks like this

```
 MINIO_ROOT_USER and MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD sets the root account for the MinIO server.
# This user has unrestricted permissions to perform S3 and administrative API operations on any resource in the deployment.
# Omit to use the default values 'minioadmin:minioadmin'.
# MinIO recommends setting non-default values as a best practice, regardless of environment

MINIO_ROOT_USER= minioadmin
MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD= minioadmin

# MINIO_VOLUMES sets the storage volume or path to use for the MinIO server.

MINIO_VOLUMES="http://1.1.1.{1...2}:9000/disk{1...3} http://1.1.1.3:9000/disk{1...3}"


MINIO_OPTS="--console-address :9001"
# MINIO_SERVER_URL sets the hostname of the local machine for use with the MinIO Server
# MinIO assumes your network control plane can correctly resolve this hostname to the local machine

# Uncomment the following line and replace the value with the correct hostname for the local machine.

#MINIO_SERVER_URL="http://minio.example.net"
MINIO_SERVER_URL="http://1.1.1.3:9000"
MINIO_HTTP_SCHEME="http"
#MINIO_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=""
#MINIO_HTTP_TLS_PRIVATE_KEY=""
```

And /etc/default/minio file of 1.1.1.1 and 1.1.1.2 is as follows

```
 MINIO_ROOT_USER and MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD sets the root account for the MinIO server.
# This user has unrestricted permissions to perform S3 and administrative API operations on any resource in the deployment.
# Omit to use the default values 'minioadmin:minioadmin'.
# MinIO recommends setting non-default values as a best practice, regardless of environment

MINIO_ROOT_USER= minioadmin
MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD= minioadmin

# MINIO_VOLUMES sets the storage volume or path to use for the MinIO server.

MINIO_VOLUMES="http://1.1.1.{1...2}:9000/disk{1...3}"


MINIO_OPTS="--console-address :9001"
# MINIO_SERVER_URL sets the hostname of the local machine for use with the MinIO Server
# MinIO assumes your network control plane can correctly resolve this hostname to the local machine

# Uncomment the following line and replace the value with the correct hostname for the local machine.

#MINIO_SERVER_URL="http://minio.example.net"
MINIO_SERVER_URL="http://1.1.1.10:9000"
MINIO_HTTP_SCHEME="http"
#MINIO_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=""
#MINIO_HTTP_TLS_PRIVATE_KEY=""
```

Error showing is
`Read failed. Insufficient number of drives online (*errors.errorString)`

Comment: IMO, you need "Expand a Distributed MinIO Deployment" guide: https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/operations/install-deploy-manage/expand-minio-deployment.html